# Work with shp and tiff in csv format

Tags: shapefile, csv, geotiff-tiff

I was wondering if its possible to make clips and other types of operations with a shp or tiff file, but all worked on a csv as using text?
What I want to do is replicate these operations in labview in csv.

I am working on a project, with shape files and raster files, and I was looking at a website that converts csv, among other formats to shape and raster files. What I want to know is the math involved when doing a clip for example, so I can replicate that in a csv file inside labview. I just want to know the math behind the processes in qgis or arcgis, so I can replicate these processes in labview, with a csv file.

Comment: with gdal you can use gdalbuildvrt for many on the fly operations.

Comment: But is it possible to work all the operations in a shape and raster file as text based in a csv format?

Comment: please specify what you want to do exactly, because right now the question is too broad to give a good answer.

Comment: I am working on a project, with shape files and raster files, and I was looking at a website that converts csv, among other formats to shape and raster files. What I want to know is the math involved when doing a clip for example, so I can replicate that in a csv file inside labview. I just want to know the math behind the processes in qgis or arcgis, so I can replicate these processes in labview, with a csv file.

Comment: please add the information to the original question by editing

Comment: `.shp`and `.tif` are ***binary*** formats. It's not possible to have binary data  as ASCII CSV and still be binary. There's a reason these formats *are* binary (because trying to work with them as ASCII would be orders of magnitude larger and slower).  You're asking for millions of lines of code, to be ported to the most inefficient format possible. This question is *inconceivably* broad, and therefore  inappropriate for GIS SE's "Focused question / Best answer" model.

Answer (score 1):

If you have point data or raster data in a CSV format, you could perform an extremely simple clip to a rectangle in your coordinate system.  You would simply exclude any data point that is above or below the desired range of values in your x and y coordinates (latitude/longitude for example).

[image: clip by excluding values outside of a particular range]

If you expect to clip using a more complicated clip boundary or you have lines or polygons that will be truncated, you would be re-writing a more complex GIS operation.